# Send message by signalr from partial view

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, signalr, razor-pages

In my razor pages app I need send message from partial view. I use signalr.
My razor page:

```
@page 
@model Pokerweb.Pages.GamePageModel
@addTagHelper *, Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.TagHelpers

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script src="~/js/signalr/dist/browser/signalr.js"></script>
<script src="~/js/chat.js"></script>

<div id="grid"></div>

<script>

    $(function () {
        $('#load').on('click', function () {
            $('#grid').load('/GamePage?handler=PlayersPartial');
        });
    });
</script>
```

Partial:

```
@using Pokerweb.Models
@model Room

<h3>@Model.Sum</h3>

<table class="table table-striped">
    @foreach (var player in Model.Players)
    {
        <tr>
            <td>@player.PlayerName</td>
            <td>@player.Money</td>
        </tr>
    }
</table>

<input type="range" min="1" max="100" value="50" class="slider" id="myRange">

<button class="btn btn-primary" id="sendButton">Send</button>
```

Chat.js:

```
"use strict";

window.onload = function () {

    var connection = new signalR.HubConnectionBuilder().withUrl("/chatHub").build();
    
    connection.on("ReceiveMessage", function () {
        $(function () {
            $('#grid').load('/GamePage?handler=PlayersPartial');
        });
    });

    connection.start().then(function () {
        document.getElementById("sendButton").disabled = false;
    }).catch(function (err) {
        return console.error(err.toString());
    });

    document.getElementById("sendButton").addEventListener("click", function (event) {
        connection.invoke("SendMessage").catch(function (err) {
            return console.error(err.toString());
        });
        event.preventDefault();
    });
};
```

By sendButton click I want fire impuls which provides some changes in database and at the end it refreshes partial view for some user. Because the result should be web page for playing poker. Almost everything there happens between players of one room. So I want to fire impuls which do some stuff with database in chathub and then send empty message to group of people in one room for updating partial view generated from updated database.

My problem is that in code here isn't send button working. It should be because js is executed before send button is build. I tryed many ways to solve this problem but noone of them works. So I need get working solution. Thanks everybody for replays and sorry for my english.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> My problem is that in code here isn't send button working. It should be because js is executed before send button is build.

As you mentioned, when the js code execute and try to attach a click event to the button `"sendButton"`, it does not be rendered in current DOM, which cause the issue.

And in your code, we can find that the content of <div> container with id  `"grid"` will be dynamically updated once a new message is received on client side, and the button `"sendButton"` will be also rerendered too.

To achieve your requirement, you can try to use a dummy button (a hidden button) in main page, and trigger it to invoke hub method when user click send button, like below.

```
<div id="grid"></div>

<input id="send_btn_trigger" type="button" style="visibility:hidden;" />

@section scripts{
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

    <script src="~/js/signalr/dist/browser/signalr.js"></script>
    <script src="~/js/chat.js"></script>

    <script>

        $(function () {
            $('#load').on('click', function () {
                $('#grid').load('/GamePage?handler=PlayersPartial', function () {
                    updategrid();
                });
            });
        });

        function triggerSendEvent() {
            console.log("triggerSendEvent");
            $("#send_btn_trigger").click();
        }
    </script>
}
```

*Partial page*

```
@model Room

<h3>@Model.Sum</h3>

<table class="table table-striped">
    @foreach (var player in Model.Players)
    {
        <tr>
            <td>@player.PlayerName</td>
            <td>@player.Money</td>
        </tr>
    }
</table>

<input type="range" min="1" max="100" value="50" class="slider" id="myRange">

<button class="btn btn-primary" id="sendButton" onclick="triggerSendEvent()" disabled>Send</button>
```

*Chat.js*

```
"use strict";

function updategrid() {
    //console.log("updategrid");
    var connection = new signalR.HubConnectionBuilder().withUrl("/chatHub").build();

    connection.on("ReceiveMessage", function () {

        $('#grid').load('/GamePage?handler=PlayersPartial', function () {
            document.getElementById("sendButton").disabled = false;
        });    
    });

    connection.start().then(function () {
        document.getElementById("sendButton").disabled = false;
    }).catch(function (err) {
        return console.error(err.toString());
    });

    document.getElementById("send_btn_trigger").addEventListener("click", function (event) {
        //console.log("send_btn_trigger");
        connection.invoke("SendMessage").catch(function (err) {
            return console.error(err.toString());
        });

        event.preventDefault();
    });
}
```

Test Result

[image]

Comment: I'm not sure if this is secure solution, but It works. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

A Problem seems to be that the `<button>` element doesn't exits when you try to select it with `document.getElementById("sendButton")`. you should try to append the handler after loading the partial like:

```
"use strict";

function appendHandlers() {
    document.getElementById("sendButton").addEventListener("click", function (event) {
        connection.invoke("SendMessage").catch(function (err) {
            return console.error(err.toString());
        });
        event.preventDefault();
    });
}

window.onload = function () {

    var connection = new signalR.HubConnectionBuilder().withUrl("/chatHub").build();
    
    connection.on("ReceiveMessage", function () {
        $(function () {
            $('#grid').load('/GamePage?handler=PlayersPartial').then(appendHandlers);
        });
    });

    connection.start().then(function () {
        document.getElementById("sendButton").disabled = false;
    }).catch(function (err) {
        return console.error(err.toString());
    });
};
```

Comment: I am sorry but I made mistake in copying my code here. I erased more than I wanted. So I edited my question and add there connection.start(). It appears in my code and It isn't reason of error working. Thanks for reply. I am really sorry.

Comment: @FoksaK i changed my answer to an other possible solution

Comment: I tried it. It doesn't help. There must be some different problem.